# How to test catch function with Jest

Tags: vue.js, mocking, axios, jestjs

How to test catch from function like this:

```
getApi () {
    const URL = '/api/division?key='
    axios.get(URL)
      .then((response) => {
        this.counter = response.data
      })
      .catch(err => {
        alert(err)
      })
  }
```

I'm using axios and vue js with testing JEST. Hope any solution, thanks :')

Answer (score 1):

Try [`axios-mock-adapter`](https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter), which can mock the results of `axios.get()` calls, allowing you to simulate a network error/timeout for a specific request (thus invoking the `catch` callback in your code):

```
import axios from "axios";
import MockAdapter from "axios-mock-adapter";

const mock = new MockAdapter(axios);
mock.onGet(`/* URL used by component */`).networkError();
```

Example unit tests for `getApi()`:

```
it("does not modify username from network error", async () => {
  mock.onGet(`/* URL used by component */`).networkError();
  await wrapper.vm.getApi();
  expect(wrapper.vm.username).toBe(INIT_USERNAME);
});

it("does not modify username from network timeout", async () => {
  mock.onGet(`/* URL used by component */`).timeout();
  await wrapper.vm.getApi();
  expect(wrapper.vm.username).toBe(INIT_USERNAME);
});
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/3xp1v90qj6?module=src/components/HelloWorld.spec.js)

Comment: @Nadya No problem :)

Comment: @NadyaPrabaningrum It looks like you can mark this as correct, also if your other questions have been answered you can use the tick to mark them as fixed.